# Registering events for a specific feed in Feed Me

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm working with Feed Me to run several feeds, bringing in multiple Entry types. I need to do some additional preparation work via an `EVENT_AFTER_PARSE_FEED` handler, which works well when I only have a single feed, but fails when I add a second feed.

I want to run the event handler for Feed A, but not for Feed B: Is there a simple way of specifying the feed when registering the event handler, or querying the event name inside the event handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems parse feed event only provide url and response. i don't know about specifying additional data for feed but some other solutions are:

- add feed name as query string to feed url (if it is url and you have have control over it) and parse url on EVENT_AFTER_PARSE_FEED to detect feed name

```
Event::on(DataTypes::class, DataTypes::EVENT_AFTER_PARSE_FEED, function (FeedDataEvent $event) {
   $url = parse_url($event->url);
   $path = $url['path'];
   $query = $url['query'];
 });
```

- using [`EVENT_BEFORE_PROCESS_FEED`](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/developers/events.html#the-beforeprocessfeed-event) and changing feed data before processing

```
<?php
use craft\feedme\events\FeedProcessEvent;
use craft\feedme\services\Process;
use yii\base\Event;
Event::on(Process::class, Process::EVENT_BEFORE_PROCESS_FEED, function(FeedProcessEvent $event) {
    if ($event->name == 'feed A') {
      foreach ($event->feedData as $key => $data) {
        $event->feedData[$key]['title'] = 'item' . $key; //changing data attribute of each data
      }
    }
});
?>
```